# GROUP BY con Min Max en mismo campo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito obtener la lista de autos que exceden un limite de velocidad de mas de 50, junto con la Fecha y hora que inicio la velocidad y la fecha que terminó

Tabla[Datos Prueba]:

[image: Tabla]

Resultado Esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```sql
--TABLA
CREATE TABLE tbRegistroVelocidad (
    Nombe VARCHAR(100),
    Velocidad FLOAT,
    Fecha DATETIME
)


--DATOS
INSERT INTO tbRegistroVelocidad(Nombe,Velocidad, Fecha) VALUES('SONIC', 65.35, '2020-04-01 13:25:35.000')
INSERT INTO tbRegistroVelocidad(Nombe,Velocidad, Fecha) VALUES('SONIC', 40.55, '2020-04-01 15:30:22.000')
INSERT INTO tbRegistroVelocidad(Nombe,Velocidad, Fecha) VALUES('SONIC', 78.76, '2020-04-02 17:12:45.000')
INSERT INTO tbRegistroVelocidad(Nombe,Velocidad, Fecha) VALUES('SONIC', 41.44, '2020-04-02 20:34:52.000')


--CONSULTA
SELECT  Automovil = Nombre,
        FechaInicio = MIN(Fecha) ,
        FechaFin =  MAX(Fecha)
FROM tbRegistroVelocidad
WHERE Velocidad > 50  
GROUP BY Nombre
```

Actualmente me sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo obtener FechaInicio y FechaFin en base al Resultado Esperado?

Comment: Que gestor usas?

Comment: Por favor añade algunos datos de prueba para poder reproducir tu ejercicio y ayudarte

Comment: @BetaM es SQL Server

Comment: Como puedo agregar datos de prueba? la primera imagen es una tabla con datos de prueba, a eso te referías ?

Comment: No, edita y pega la declaración SQL para la creación de tu tabla y el insert de algunos datos, de esa forma nosotros podemos hacer pruebas para responderte

Comment: @BetaM ah ok, lo edito thks

Comment: @BetaM listo, entiendo que el WHERE Velocidad > 50 estoy descartando los que no son mayores a 50 y por eso la FechaFin no es la correcta, pero no comprendo como realizar la consulta para tener en ambos campos ambas fechas en base a las Velocidades

Comment: @BetaM ese es el problema. El reporte que solicitan debe tener como FechaInicio la primer Velocidad Maxima alcanzada, mientras que la FechaFin debe tener la primer Velocidad NO maxima. y asi sucesivamente. El de las 15:30 deberia ser la FechaFinal del primer registro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si los datos están en orden [Velocidad inicial y después velocidad final]:

```
SELECT  t.Nombe as Nombre, Fecha as FechaInicio,

(
  select top 1  Fecha 
  from tbRegistroVelocidad 
  where Nombe = t.nombe and Fecha > t.fecha 

) as FechaFin

FROM tbRegistroVelocidad t

WHERE Velocidad > 50
```

La `fechaFin` se calcula tomando la primer fecha que sea mayor que la `fechaInicio` y que tenga el mismo nombre del registro donde la velocidad es mayor a 50.